CSRF token is missing Superset
I am facing the issue of "message": "400 Bad Request: The CSRF token is missing.", When I am trying to embed Superset with this node @superset-ui/embedded-sdk", My current setting in config.py are
'''
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_SERVER_SIDE = False
TALISMAN_ENABLED = False
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
'''
are this, Please let me know where i am missing .
